# For load testing , is it mandate to do Response Assertion ? If so , is there any overhead in doing assertion ( jmeter)

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

For load testing using JMeter,

Is it mandate to do Response Assertion ? If so , is there any overhead in doing assertion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, and there's an overhead of resource usage

[Best practice](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) is to use minimun assertions

> Use as few Assertions as possible

Also you can use JSR223 Assertion to check response using code

Comment: Thank you for the response , so If we are using JSR223 Assertion , there will not be overhead ? 
In general can you please explain what overload here means ? Does it affect the load generators ? or the avg response tim e?

Comment: @Pasa overhead is for any assertion , shouldn't affect response time, but uses machine resources to process response which may add time to the overall time of test execution